# how can I view the execution plan of a mongoose.js query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to verify that the mongoose query that I'm creating is using my indexes.  Is there a way that I can view the final query that is generated to mongodb so that I can run a .explain() on the query?

I can guess what the query it is generating is, but just wanted to verify.

e.g.

```
 var query = Post.find()
   .regex('lowerCaseTitle', searchRegEx)
   .$gte('status',0)
   .$lt('start', now)
   .$gt('end',now)
   .sort('total', -1)
   .limit(50);
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

One way is to use the mongodb profiler and set it to log all operations:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler

I'm not sure if there's a simpler way to do it through mongoose itself, but that would be nice.

Update: Adding to what Dan said in the other answer's comment, you should turn the profiler on to get what you want, and turn it back off. Leaving it as "log all operations" is definitely a good way to slow down your system. Limiting it to a development environment is a good idea, also.

Answer (score 53):

You can get the execution query using the debug option on mongoose:

```
mongoose.set('debug', true);
```

or

```
mongoose.set('debug', function (collectionName, method, query, doc, options) {
  //
});
```

Answer (score 11):

Another option:

```
model
  .find()
  .{{...}} // any thing else
  .setOptions({explain: 'executionStats'})
  .exec((e, explainObj)=>{
     ...
  })
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use [Query.prototype.explain()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-explain) directly (as Mongoose 5.2.13)

```
 var query = Post.find()
   .regex('lowerCaseTitle', searchRegEx)
   .$gte('status',0)
   .$lt('start', now)
   .$gt('end',now)
   .sort('total', -1)
   .limit(50);
query.explain().then(console.log);
```

Answer (score -2):

The easiest approach might be to just replicate that query in the MongoDB shell. Something like:

```
> var now = new Date();
> db.post.find({lowerCaseTitle: /your_regex_here/, status: {$gte: 0}, start: {$lt: now}, end: {$gt: now}}).sort({total: -1}).limit(50)
```

This should return the same results as you get from the query in mongoose.js. You can then add a `.explain()` to see the execution plan used by MongoDB:

```
> db.post.find({lowerCaseTitle: /your_regex_here/, status: {$gte: 0}, start: {$lt: now}, end: {$gt: now}}).sort({total: -1}).limit(50).explain()
```

Comment: I could guess at the query that it's creating, but I wanted to verify to make sure that was indeed what was being sent to mongo from mongoose.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I misunderstood. In that case, you could verify by using the profiler as Wes Freeman suggests, but I would do so only during development, not in production. The profiler carries some overhead, so it is not recommended for production use.